# Battery lifetime about a fifth what it should be

Tags: batteries, esp8266

I have an esp8266-201 hooked up to an LM3671 buck converter breakout that is in turn connected to a 3x AAA battery pack.

The capacity of the battery pack should be at least 1200 mAh at 4.5 volts.

The apparatus draws about 100 mA while awake and about 0.175 mA while sleeping (taken with a multimeter), and it is programmed on a 60 s sleep, 3 s wake cycle. This corresponds to an average current draw should be 100*(3/63) + 0.175*(60/63) = ~5 mA.

The device only runs for approximately 2 days or about 48 hours meaning that it is registering an average current draw of 25 mA.

What is going on here?

**EDIT:**

I powered the device using batteries from the same pack as the ones that failed earlier. I made sure all the batteries had voltages of ~1.6 V before placing them in the pack. I loosely monitored the voltage of the battery pack over time.

N.B. I realized a flaw in my firmware was causing the ESP8266 to draw more power than needed for my application. I changed the settings and managed to about half the wake current to ~55 mA. The average current is now about 2.5 mA

[image]

Although I halved the wake current the device did not last twice as long. It ran exceptionally until about the 50 hour mark where it began to drop off quickly. Does this signify bad batteries or something else?

It seem like the batteries discharged in the manner that they should, they just exhibited a much lower mAh then they should. I am particularly perplexed that halving the current did not double the run time. **What is happening here?**

Comment: What is the capacity of each battery? What is the output of the buck converter? Have you actually measured the currents in two of the modes?

Comment: What is the battery voltage after 2 days?  Drawing 100 ma from an AAA battery will drop its voltage significantly after a few hours. It may still have energy left but not at enough voltage to power your circuit.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. The capacity of each battery should be about 1200 mAh. The output of the buck converter is 3.3 V. I have actually measured the currents in the two modes.

Comment: @Barry The voltage for the entire pack after 2 days is about 2.8 V.

Comment: Have you _actually_ measured what your buck converter drains from the batteries? Or are you measuring your ESP and blue-sky-ing about the static losses in the buck converter?

Comment: @Asmyldof I measured the current between the positive lead of the battery pack and Vin on the buck converter.

Comment: Allrighty, just checking. The bulky bulk of questions to the exact same tune jump from "My MCU does" to "So battery should be" ignoring the presence of a Buck regulator with a quiescent current of 20mA.

Comment: @Asmyldof I totally understand. I chose the LM3671 mostly because of it's exceptional quiescent current.

Comment: I would normally suspect your sleep/wake cycle isn't what you think it is, or you have some other power drain (signal driven against a pulling resistor, or an off-board debug or communication interface).  But if you want to truly suspect the batteries you could sacrifice one cell to a capacity test with a power resistor calculated for a similar load.  Note also that **burden voltage** can make sleep/wake measurements tricky, in particular a device may not be able to boot and enter sleep mode while a meter on a scale that can measure the sleep current is inline.

Comment: This sure doesn't make sense. You should be getting a much higher capacity out of AAA batteries.  It may have something to do with your minimum voltage requirement.  Over the life of the alkaline AAA, it averages only 1.2 volts, so based on your minimum voltage required, you will drop below it when only 1/2 or less of the capacity is used.  It will depend on the current draw.  It does not take much current at all to cause the AAA to drop voltage.  I may be wrong, but I think I remember that the capacity tests on some of the AAA were done at only 10mA. So 55mA or 100mA might cause voltage sag.

Comment: Can you try 4 AAA in series to give you a larger voltage buffer?  Even though your average current is only 2.5mA, you do have bursts of 55mA that might be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What makes you think you're actually draining the batteries?**

The batteries are not going to provide you with 4.5V all through the 1200 mAh of charge. The voltage is going to drop. According to your measurement(s) the battery pack drops to below (I assume) ~3.3V after two days of discharge. At which point your buck doesn't have anything to buck and the rest of your system browns out.

Try using a buck/boost to get more out of your battery pack.

[image]

Comment: This is true. The pack drops to about 2.8 V (at this point the ESP-201 can't run anymore) after 2 days. I just expected the device to be able to run longer than that. The batteries are duracell coppertops. [This](http://rightbattery.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/1-5v-aaa-duracel-copper-top-vs-duracell-procell-alkaline-batteries-capacity.jpg) graph says the capacity at a 100 mA load should be about 970 mAh. I'm getting about 240 mAh out of them.

Comment: @Alex How many times has this under capacity occurred?

Comment: This is the first run I have made with the device. I recently bought the batteries from a local hardware store. Could the batteries be bad?

Comment: @Alex It's certainly appears that way. Assuming all your measurements were accurate, there isn't abnormally high temperature, or some other confounding variable, it seems the most likely reason for the poor performance.

Comment: Have you measured each AAA battery individually for voltage?  Very likely that you have one bad battery of the three, but best to replace all three as never good to put used with new batteries.  Of note, alkaline batteries do drop voltage very quickly with currents higher than 100 mA or so, so make sure you current measurents are accurate. Rechargeable NiMh AAA can supply much higher currents and hold their voltage (although the they will start at a voltage closer to 1.3 volts each). Let us know what you find

Comment: @Filek I've edited my post with some of my findings. It seems like the battery's lifetime mostly independent of the devices current draw. This is extremely unusual to me.

Answer (score 1):

Samuel was right, it seems as if the batteries I had used originally were bad. The device has been running for about 100h now, and the battery voltage is 4.14 V under sleep load and 4.02 under wake load.